# Flutter Application stuck on First Time launching

Tags: flutter, firebase, performance, dart, android-13

My Flutter Application stuck on launching screen when i open it first time and when i'm re-run Or Open application again then working fine in Android 13.

[image: In my main file i used this code]

[image: logcat]

I'm trying to run in Android 13 but screen freeze on launching screen on First Time Open application

Comment: Welcome to SO. It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)